# Assembly MIPS Stack, keep .data

Tags: sorting, assembly, stack, mips, quicksort

Hello I'm trying to make a Quicksort, sorting algorithm using assembly (MIPS). I'm fairly new to assembly and I'm having some problems with how to use the stack in my program.

What I am trying to do is to use the stack in order to make the quicksort subroutine recursive. The problem I get when doing this is that the array that I'm trying to sort when moving the stack pointer.

Here's the code:

```
main:

    li $s4, 0            # Min value of the range inside the array you want to sort
    li $s5, 15           # Max value of the range inside the array that you want to sort
    add $t6, $zero, $s4  # left-value
    add $t7, $zero, $s5  # right-value
    addiu $sp, $sp, -12  # We need space for the register $ra and register $a0 
    sw $ra, 0($sp)       # A must have, if you wanna come back and avoid strange behaviour 
    sw $s4, 4($sp)
    sw $s5, 8($sp) 
    jal quickSort
    nop
    ori $v0,$zero,10     # Prepare syscall to exit program cleanly
    syscall                

quickSort:

    move $a0, $zero
    add $a0, $zero, $t6   # Min value of the range inside the array you want to sort
    move $a1, $zero
    add $a1, $zero, $t7   # Max value of the range inside the array that you want to sort
    li $t5, 4             # Temp to mult with
    move $t3, $zero
    add $t3, $a0, $a1
    div $t3, $t3, 2
    mult $t3, $t5
    mflo $t3
    lw $s0, data($t3)     # Pivot = (min size + max size) / 2

    mult $a1, $t5         # offset for min value
    mflo $s1,             # offset for array min
    mult $a2, $t5         # offset for max value
    mflo $s2              # offset for array max 

sortLoop:

    bgt $a0, $a1, endLoop # While min value is less or equal to max value
    nop
leftLoop:
    lw $t4, data($s1)
    bge $t4, $s0, rightLoop
    nop 
    add $s1, $s1, 4
    add $a0, $a0, 1
    j leftLoop
    nop
rightLoop:
    lw $t5, data($s2)
    ble $t5, $s0, switchValue
    nop
    add $s2, $s2, -4
    add $a1, $a1, -1
    j rightLoop
    nop
switchValue:
    bgt $a0, $a1, repeat
    nop
    sw $t5, data($s1)
    sw $t4, data($s2)
    add $s1, $s1, 4
    add $a0, $a0, 1
    add $s2, $s2, -4
    add $a1, $a1, -1
repeat:
    j sortLoop              
endLoop:

recursion:
    bge $s4, $a1, recursion2
    nop

    addiu $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 8($sp)

    move $t6, $zero
    add $t6, $t6, $s4        # left-value
    move $t7, $zero
    add $t7, $t7, $a1
    jal quickSort
    nop
recursion2:
    bge $a0, $s5,endSorting
    nop

    addiu $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 8($sp)

    move $t6, $zero
    add $t6, $zero, $a0
    move $t7, $zero
    add $t7, $zero, $s5
    jal quickSort
    nop     
endSorting:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    lw $s4, 4($sp)
    lw $s5, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12  
    jr $ra 
    nop
```

My questions are as following:

- Does the `.data` values also go to the stack?
- Is this the proper use of the stack?
- If not is there any good tutorials or something that can help me learn it better?

Comment: I am not (yet) very knownledgeable about MIPS, but it seems that you forgot to pop back the values you pushed in `main`. In the `recursion` part, you push a bunch of words twice, but pop them back once. Also, you reserve 4 words (16 bytes) of stack, but only use 3 words (12 bytes) of them. You'd probably want to use offsets 0/4/8 instead of 0/8/12 like you do (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: That's not how `div` works.

Comment: @Bregalad Hmm you might be correct I will look that up, but I was thinking that the endloop will always excecute before exiting the subrouting, popping back the stack to normal. Also yes, I had a value there before which I removed I had forgotten to change it, thank you for noticing!

Comment: @EOF According to the intellisense that pops up when I write the `div` I should be able to immediately divide a register with an integer instead of moving the value to the hi/lo register. I don't know if that is the wrong way to do it but it seems to be working in my case.

Comment: Well, according to `MIPS32TM Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32TM Instruction Set`, `div` takes two registers, divides them and writes the results to `hi/lo` in the multiply/divide unit. Kinda like you'd expect when dealing with MIPS multiplications/divisions.